# Pandas convert dataframe to array of tuples with some special requirements

Tags: python, pandas

I'm analysing some data with Apriori algorithm. This requires me to convert the dataframe into an array of tuples( groupby col"c1"), with each tuple corresponding to a "row" of the dataframe. If there's only one value in the tuple, I want an "," behind it cuz I need to keep it as a tuple.

```
In [1]: data
Out[1]:
   c1   c2
0  r1   aa
1  r1   bb
2  r1   cc
3  r2   dd
4  r2   ee
5  r3   ff
```

I expect the data like this:

```
[('aa','bb','cc'),('dd','ee'),('ff',)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with `tuple` and convert `Series` to `list`:

```
a = df.groupby('c1')['c2'].apply(tuple).tolist()
print (a)
[('aa', 'bb', 'cc'), ('dd', 'ee'), ('ff',)]
```